# split по регулярному выражению с сохранением разделителя python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, текст

есть следующая строка с выражением

```
sentences = re.split(r'\.\s[А-Я]', text)
```

она сплитит текст, но не сохраняет разделители в конце предложений и заглавные буквы в начале.
как можно сплитнуть текст с сохранением разделителей?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите примеры ваших данных - какой текст у вас есть и что вы хотите получить, как вы хотите его разделить.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, такая регулярка подойдёт:

```
r'(?<=\.)\s+(?=[А-ЯЁ])'
```